# Change the color of static text C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, window

I created the dialog form for MFC class by editing .rc file with form designer as follows,
[image]

I want to change the color of above *Namodaya Balaarachchi* text field.
But there is no any property in following properties window.

[image]

Can anyone help me to change the color of above static text?

Comment: This may be useful: [Static Control Background Color with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4495814/7582247)

Comment: I tried it. But it does not work because I cannot call to CALLBACK function. 
Could you please help me to call CALLBACK function?

Answer (score 2):

I am using visual studio 2017 and create a Dialog based MFC project. After that choose "Resource View" and double click to open the dialog. Right click and choose Class Wizard, at Message, double click WM_CTLCOLOR, and select OnCtlColor, and Edit Code, add following "switch" section.

```
HBRUSH CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CDialogEx::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    // TODO:  Change any attributes of the DC here
    switch (nCtlColor)
    {
    case CTLCOLOR_STATIC:
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
        return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    }
    // TODO:  Return a different brush if the default is not desired
    return hbr;
}
```

F5 run, and the text change to red:

[image]

Comment: I think such message "WM_CTLCOLOR" should exist in 2015/2012 or even earlier visual studio.