# text menu as created window behaviour of highlighting

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I have created a Windows application.  The elements that I create are using subclassing as I wanted to handle mouse hover events.

```
DWORD dwStyleOfIcons = SS_BITMAP | SS_NOTIFY | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER;
img1 = CreateWindow(L"STATIC", NULL, dwStyleOfIcons,
            posX, posY, imgWt, imgHt,
            hWnd, (HMENU)ICON1_CLICKED, hInst, NULL);
SetWindowSubclass(img1, StaticSubClassWndProc, ICON1_CLICKED, 0);
```

In my `StaticSubClassWndProc()`, I handle `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, `WM_MOUSELEAVE`, and `WM_MOUSEHOVER`:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK StaticSubClassWndProc (HWND  hwndsubclass, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp, UINT_PTR uidsubclass , DWORD_PTR dwrefdata)
{
    ...
    switch(Msg)
    {
        case WM_MOUSEHOVER: {
            if(uidsubclass  == ICON1_CLICKED){
              texture = "texture2.bmp";
               modifyImage(texture);
            }
            break;
        }
        
        case WM_MOUSELEAVE: {
           if(uidsubclass  == ICON1_CLICKED){
               texture = "texture.bmp";
               modifyImage(texture);
            }
            break;
        }
```

There are many `STATIC` items in my application, which all I wanted the behavior of a pop up context menu, like when I hover over the image it changes to a selected image, and when the cursor is out of view the image changes back to normal. I was able to do that.

I was able to do this for images which act as icons, but how do I do it for static text controls? Essentially, in a pop up menu, the selected text is all highlighted:

[image]

Is there no simpler way to make my elements in this window behave like a pop up menu? All I want is this custom structure of pop up menu behavior.

Comment: Are you asking how to specify colors for a `STATIC` control? Have the *parent* window's WndProc handle the [`WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorstatic) message for that.

Comment: i intend to change color of the window in the mouse hover and leave event in the text static control . how can i do that ?

Comment: As I said earlier, you need to make the parent window handle the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message. Declare a color variable, and apply it whenever `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` is received. In the mouse events, update the variable and `InvalidateRect()` the `STATIC` control to trigger a repaint, which will send a new message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not handle the [`TrackMouseEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackmouseevent) function correctly, which caused your child window to be unable to process the `WM_MOUSEHOVER` and `WM_MOUSELEAVE` messages.

I tested the following code and it worked for me:

```
HBITMAP hBmp1 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"test1.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 200, 300, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
HBITMAP hBmp2 = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"test2.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 200, 300, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
HWND img1;

LRESULT CALLBACK StaticSubClassWndProc(HWND  hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uidsubclass, DWORD_PTR dwrefdata)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT lpEventTrack;
        lpEventTrack.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
        lpEventTrack.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
        lpEventTrack.hwndTrack = img1;
        lpEventTrack.dwHoverTime = 100;
        TrackMouseEvent(&lpEventTrack);
        break;
    }
    case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
    {
        if (uidsubclass == ICON1_CLICKED) {
            SendMessage(hwnd, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBmp1);
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
    {
        if (uidsubclass == ICON1_CLICKED) {
            SendMessage(hwnd, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBmp2);
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

But you need to be aware that `WM_MOUSEHOVER` and `WM_MOUSELEAVE` will trigger frequently, so I don't think you should use this method to load pictures when the mouse is hovered or left, which will frequently trigger the loading of pictures.

Comment: i did handled WM_MOUSEMOVE (left it by mistake) . i intend to change color of the window in the mouse hover and leave event in the text static control . how can i do that ?

Comment: Regarding performance , how can i improve that if i want to replicate pop up behaviour ie when mouse is hovered on item things change for that item in visual manner

Comment: I think you cannot dynamically change the color of a static control in this way. You can only modify its background color by [processing the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495509/static-control-background-color-with-c). As for the efficiency issue, when you choose to use this method, you can only try to Avoid frequently triggering `WM_MOUSELEAVE` and `WM_MOUSEHOVER` messages back and forth.